# Why does the solve error keep changing?

Tags: tracking

I've been doing a simple camera track, I placed 8 markers and thought now is a good time to see what the solve error is: 11.4301

[image: track]

The confusing thing is, that if I press Solve Camera Motion repeatedly I keep getting different solve errors, even though I have changed absolutely nothing since the last time I did a solve.

[image: second solve]

[image: third solve]

Am I doing something wrong? It doesn't seem correct to me, surely whatever algorithms are running to do the solve won't change after each click without me influencing it in some way.

Comment: Yes, sometimes solving the scene again yields different error numbers, I'm not sure if previous solution is taking into account on a new one... Not really an answer as to why, but since you have the "Keframe" box checked on the Solve tab, Blender is probably giving the trackers different weight in the solution.  From the Wiki: "Automatic Keyframe Selection
Added an option to select keyframes used for initial reconstruction automatically (r57133).

This option enables some fancy math algorithms which tries to find a keyframe pair with minimal reconstruction error and best scene scale guess. "

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.68/Motion_Tracker

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if this is the intended behaviour then it is problematic for the following reason. My initial solve error was not the best one i could achieve, does this mean users are supposed to keep solving in with possibility of achieving better results? I managed to get it to 3 from 11 without any changes at all, and this was without any further refinement of focal point etc.

Comment: Aim for the lowest error possible, using every possible trick: refining tracks, undistorting, etc. "Basically, reprojection error below 0.3 means accurate reprojection, 0.3-3.0 means quite nice solving which still can be used. Values above 3 means some tracks should be tracked more accurately, or that values for focal length or distortion coefficients were set incorrectly." http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking

Comment: I understand what you're saying about solve errors, but this must surely be a bug!

Comment: @cegaton How do I know what the focal length and distortion coefficients are?  By the way, I have experienced this same problem, but the solve error has increased by 40 without changing anything.  Weird...

Comment: @AnsonSavage  For the lens distortion see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-tweak-k1- k2-and-k3-undistortion-values-in-motion-tracking for the lens you ahve to do a bit of research on what lens and sensor your camera uses or use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtorres.phonetester&hl=en ....   please read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/lens-specs-of-smartphones-for-camera-tracking-in-blender/16136#16136 and for other questions **please make a new post**

Comment: @AnsonSavage what I did was simply set the `refine` option right above the solve button to "focal length, k1, k2", which means it will try to guess the focal length and distortion automatically. Or, if you use the trick to find distortion that cegaton provided above, but you still don't know the focal length, you can set refine to focal length only

Comment: @Markasoftware So will focal length k1 k2 guess all that stuff for any camera, or just specific cameras? What do k1 and k2 mean?

Comment: It'll guess for any camera