# Can I make a camera use the lens distortion parameters determined by camera tracking?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, camera, tracking

The camera tracking utilities allow you to specify or estimate lens distortion parameters (k1, k2, and k3).  Is it possible to get the Blender camera to adopt this specific distortion?  I can't find a way to set these directly on the camera.  Nor can I find a way to get the lens distortion in the compositor to take these.

I have a really great track on a very wide angle scene with a very nice distortion.  I can't seem to match the distortion perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Once you've determined the distortion values using the movie clip editor's lens distortion's tools you can use them on blender scenes using the compositor.
You need to add a **Movie Distortion** node in **Distort** mode, to your render layer. Make sure you select select the video clip as source.

[image]

Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15622/1853

Comment: For some reason I didn't even notice the Movie Distortion node type (probably since it doesn't seem to be documented).  Sigh.  Even more convenient than I had hoped for.  Thanks again, @cegaton!

Comment: @Chuck It's confusing indeed, especially since there is also a lens distort node that's unrelated to lens distortion on the movie clip editor...