# How do you take reference photos?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model my face on Blender using [this tutorial](http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/female-character-modeling-in-blender-part-1--cms-19723) and it gives links to reference photos.

The thing is, as I mentioned above, I want to try and model my face.

So I've decided to take photos of my face. But it doesn't seem to be working well (not symmetrical enough and stuff), so how exactly should I take my reference photos so that it would work well when I try to model it with the Mirror modifier?

Note: I only have the 'webcam' on my Macbook Pro and the camera on my Hongmi phone and I don't want to spend money on a new camera.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Photography.SE site.

Comment: I think you can answer this yourself. If symmetry is your problem then take more symmetrical shot or adjust the picture in photoshop. If quality is bad then get better lighting or better camera. Don't know what answers you expect.

Comment: Ideally you'll want to take the picture from far away while zoomed in. This will reduce perspective, making the picture more like the orthographic projection you'll be modeling in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your phone camera, and hold it as far away as possible to reduce lens deformation. Hold the camera so the lens is at eye's height, as centered as possible. Cut the photo in two using gimp or other 2D software, and mirror it. Even professional taken photos have some non symmetricsl details.

Also take a shot in profile, at the same distance and height, and adjust to keep as close as possible the proportions between the two shoots.

Use the reference just as it is: a reference not a sharp point-to-point grid.

Comment: Lens deformation shouldn't be an issue. You can [un-distort in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622) I would suggest to be close enough so that most of the object you need is in the frame and you have more pixels to work from.

Answer (score 2):

Things you need:

- office chair (or any that rotates)
- tripod or another thing to hold your camera/phone
- good lighting

Steps:

1. Setup the tripod with your camera/phone.
2. Setup timer on camera to take multiple shots or take a video.
3. Sit straight on the chair and rotate around.
4. Correct minor deformations/symetrics in photoshop