# Weird warping of render image in Camera track

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, tracking

[image]
Hi guys, Please help me fix the render image as there are weird warping in the corners of the image. I'm using cycles.

Comment: If you are un-distorting the image that is natural.  Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113907/motion-tracking-the-edges-of-undistorted-footage-are-cropped-and-so-are-the-el and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38478/why-is-my-footage-smearing-out-towards-the-border-on-rendering-an-image/38489#38489 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Comment: Hi, This issue here is only caused by wither the render itself or by the camera track.

Comment: I dont think it's a nodal thing.

Comment: yeah it's my bad i haven't mentioned im actually relatively new to blender.

Comment: I actually am not sure on what examples you're specifying. Could you please let me know but i can say that the refine in the solve that is Focal length, K1, K2.

Comment: I hope this helps at all