# How to stop background video stretching?

Tags: rendering, video

[image]

it is not like this in the render only in the viewport. But this makes it hard to line things up when my viewport is different then my render. My video is 1920x1080 and my project is 1920by 1080 so i dont know why it is stretching.

Comment: Is this motion tracked video?

Comment: [why is my footage smearing out towards the border on renderintg an image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38478/why-is-my-footage-smearing-out-towards-the-border-on-rendering-an-image/38489#38489) and [how to determine lens distortion coefficients for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622) and [edges of the tracked image are cropped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113907/motion-tracking-the-edges-of-undistorted-footage-are-cropped-and-so-are-the-el)