# Superimposing architectural models onto street photographs

Tags: photorealism

I wanted to use 3D MAX to create architectural renders, but I have a Mac, so I am looking into Blender as an alternative solution.

The models look amazing and the rendering is fab, but I am struggling to find a tutorial to help me superimpose my model onto the photograph of a street or equivalent. I have to supply images of the model in situ, so I am really hoping there is a way. Please can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you narrow down your post to a less vague question.This site is not meant to recommend tutorials. Here are some related posts to get you started,. Read: [recreate geometry based on a photograph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph/102750#102750) and [align grid to background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330) and [moedeling from google maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97108/tips-for-modelling-from-google-maps/97119#97119)

Comment: read also: [realistic rendering of mesh and image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154792/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-2-8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52204/is-there-a-way-to-know-camera-information-from-an-image-visually-without-exif/52207#52207

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place your models so they look like they are part of a photograph, you should be looking for VFX (video effects) tutorials.
CG Geek has a few on YouTube, where he adds objects to video footage, but the same techniques apply for still photographs.
Blender Guru has some too.  Try searching for "How to render onto a photo background" on his website.