# Lens distortion algorithm in Movie Clip Editor

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

Which lens undistortion algorithm is used in Blender?
I want to know more about these K1, K2, K3 parameters. How do they work? How they relate to each other. Why I need K2 and K3 if K1 does the job?
Any info will be usefull.

Comment: read: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/106/article_lr.pdf

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-tweak-k1-k2-and-k3-undistortion-values-in-motion-tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are just the factors of parabolic and quadratic distortion, as well as a distortion of power 6. lens distortion has to be symmetric/isotrtopic, hence it can be written as function of a pixels distance to the center. this distance changes with an towards the center (=distortion).

The new distorted distance to the center is 
D_r(r) = r+ k1*(r)^2 + k2*(r)^4 + k3*(r)^6

with r being the distance in pixels. So its rather just mathematical parameters, that approximate real lens distortion, than any parameters of real lenses present in your camera.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Where did you find the equation? It looks similar to OpenCV distortion model. So Blender uses OpenCV's equation or not? Do you have more info about the topic?