# What Lens Model does Blender use for Camera Tracking?

Tags: camera, tracking

I recently started working with the camera-tracking estimator to produce short augmented reality videos. I'd like to learn more about the lens model and its parameters (K1, K2, etc...).

Can anyone tell me the specific name of this lens model, or the general theory it belongs to? Would this model/theory fall be covered by the general study of undergraduate-level Optics as taught by a Physics department, or in what book or article would I be able to learn more about it? (Assuming I meet any basic calculus and linear algebra prerequisites).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Blender works with a ***pinhole camera*** matrix. Where an image is created by a projection of the 3d coordinates into a 2d plane.

[image]

k1, k2 etc are [radial distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)) coefficients. Blender does not deal with tangential distortion.

For a deeper explanation refer to the following links:

[http://lfa.mobivap.uva.es/~fradelg/phd/tracking/camera.html](http://lfa.mobivap.uva.es/%7Efradelg/phd/tracking/camera.html)

https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/camera-models

[3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera)

You can get more information also reading on OpenCV and camera calibration.

Comment: I cannot upvote here, but thank you! Would it be correct then to say that k1 & k2 are the 2nd-order and 4th-order polynomial coefficients as given in the 2nd link in your citations section?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you look into  the Brown Conrady distortion models you should be able to find the correct answer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/lens-distortion-algorithm-in-movie-clip-editor