# How to apply lens polynomial distortion to an image

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image, movie-clip-editor

I have seen in the internet that it can be done using the Movie Clip Editor. So I import an image and introduce the parameters needed, but for some reason nothing happens and distortion does not apply. Is this happening because I should be using a clip instead of a picture or am I missing something? Maybe render again somehow? Looks like distortion applies on the grid when it is displayed though.

Here some pictures of my environment configuration:

[image: Movie Clip Editor view]

[image: Camera configuration]

[image: Render configuration]

Thanks

Comment: First image, right side: *Display* > **Render Undistorted**

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-tweak-k1-k2-and-k3-undistortion-values-in-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have a movie clip or a single image.