# Overscan in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

In our VFX workflow, we are matchmoving shots in Blender and also calculating lens distortion in Blender with the Camera Solver.

To get the distortion data over to our compositing app we are applying the distortion to a UV image or an STmap as they are called in Nuke.

All of that works fine. What I'm trying to solve now is how to create a bit of overscan in the image to compensate for distortion that expands past the frame boundary.

Specifically, I want to do this in the compositor outputting to the File Output node as seen in the setup here. How can I expand the frame bounds but leave this UV image in the center where it is without scaling?

[image]

Comment: I think here is the answer: https://youtu.be/qH8JzDxbB7E 105% in the renderoutput

Comment: to make the undistorded frame fit within the render, make change the frame size larger in the Dimension->Resolution settings like in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113907/motion-tracking-the-edges-of-undistorted-footage-are-cropped-and-so-are-the-el

Comment: yep! I worked with Sean to figure out the solution.