# I'm getting a distortioned weird effect when ''Setting up the tracking scene'' in my movie clip editor

Tags: rendering, tracking, movie-clip-editor

[image]

Whenever I look into my 3d viewport through my camera I see this weird effects, how do I get rid of them? My resolution matches the footage's

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113907/motion-tracking-the-edges-of-undistorted-footage-are-cropped-and-so-are-the-el