# Motion tracking : How to solve camera using lens distorted footage

Tags: tracking

What is the best workflow to solve camera track using footage that has lens distortion ? do i have to undistort the clip first using external app ? or can Blender do the undistortion using its internal tool before i feed it to camera tracker ? Or any other better method ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tweak K1, K2 and K3 undistortion values in motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-tweak-k1-k2-and-k3-undistortion-values-in-motion-tracking)

Comment: Read also: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)