# Help with determining camera specs? Blender Motion Tracking

Tags: camera, video, tracking, motion-capture

I have some experience working with Blender's motion tracking capabilities, but have only used cell phone video that happened to be presets in the camera specs dropdown in Blender.

I am trying to do some motion tracking with a drone video, and really have no idea how to interpret the camera specs.

Was wondering if anyone could help me with this?

https://www.dji.com/ca/phantom-4-adv/info#specs

Trying to find the: sensor width, focal length, lens distortion coefficients (if required).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Finding lens distortion is a must. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Comment: You don't necessarily need the sensor width or lens size. Use the preset for a 35mm full frame camera and use a 24mm lens size (as stated by the specs). A bit of google will help you find the info as well: http://vfxcamdb.com/dji-phantom-4-advanced/ Sensor Dimensions:
12.8 mm x 7.2 mm (0.504 in x 0.283 in) FOV 84° Lens size 8.8 mm (/24 mm (35 mm format equivalent)

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, there are some presets in Blender for certain cameras. In Properties area.
[image]

Make sure you are in Object Mode and the Camera is selected. I found this info recently, myself.

Comment: thanks, I was aware of this, but the camera I am using was not one of the presets