# Blender Camera Settings Millimeters/Field of View conversion

Tags: camera

I have a question concerning the camera setting. You can choose between tweaking the field of view or the mm settings.

I use a 50 mm objective on my canon 6d. The field of view for this lense is at a fixed 46° angle.

So I set up the camera in my scene and set it to 50 mm. when i switsh to field of view it is set to 39,4° which ist more narrow than the angle of my real world objective.

Which settings should i use to fit my real world camera objective?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Full frame sensor right? If so, set the lens to 50, enter the proper sensor size and you are literally done. Consider to add lens distortion within the compositor to match the characteristics of the actual lens...

Comment: How can i simulate the distortion of my lens?

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **sensor's** size plays a role either. Wikipedia says:

> So a standard 50 mm lens for 35 mm photography acts like a 50 mm standard "film" lens on a professional digital SLR, but would act closer to an 80 mm lens (1.6 x 50mm) on many mid-market DSLRs, and the 40 degree angle of view of a standard 50 mm lens on a film camera is equivalent to a 28–35 mm lens on many digital SLRs.

Hence, you need to increase the sensor's size to 42.447 
I believe there's a formula for this.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_6D) it is `35.8` mm (it's a full frame dlsr so there is no need to calculate something).

Comment: I already set the right consor size, set the objective to 50 mm. But does Blender set the FOV to another Value?