# Camera Footage appears stretched in render window

Tags: rendering, camera

[image]I'm quite new to blender and i have been doing a Donut and completed it . right now i just wanna put it in a live footage. hence i've tracked camera and set up plane, origin, solved the camera and even arranged my model to suit it . But the problem is my footage appears to be stretched in the render view. I've attached the Snapshot below. please help me get out of it. Thank you ! I've matched the footage's resolutions to the output settings too. however it's an image sequence [image: re]

Comment: Did you undistort the video? Show an image of the nodes in the compostitor.

Comment: @susu Hello Thank you for replying. I'm new to it and I don't know what you're talking about . But my compositor shows something related to undistortion. Please do have a look at it. I've edited and attached the image. Thank you !

Comment: In the movie distort node change the setting from distort to undistort. Read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622 to understand what you are up against.

Comment: @susu alright! Thank you.