# Camera and lens settings/preset for iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: camera, tracking

I've recorded some footage using my iPhone 11 Pro that I want to track. Using Google I found that the primary lens (the one I used) has a focal length of 26 mm. However, I understand that for proper tracking I also need to know the Sensor Width and lens distortion values (K1, K2, K3). I've found some articles that explain how to calculate them, but that's quite a lot of work. Has anyone already calculated these values? Pretty strange that Blender 2.90 doesn't come with presets for recent iPhones. After all I think they're one of the most used 4K 60 fps cameras.

Comment: Since the phone allows to zoom, K values are different per zoom factor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine lens undistortion values for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking)

Comment: I have to agree. Iphone 5 is the most recent one on my version of Blender (2.81a)

Comment: @brockmann I had already found that article myself. As I've said I don't want to calculate it myself. I'm looking for the values (i.e. a preset) of the iPhone 11's primary lens, at 1x zoom.

Comment: @brockmann Does that mean every iPhone 11 Pro has unique values for this?

Comment: If you know the lens size, and sensor size you can make your own preset and save it. To calculate the distortion values use the tools in blender (it is hard to do with external tools). Note that there is no way for you to use the distortion values from other phones, as distortion coefficients are unique to each lens. Distortion coefficients will also be different if the lens is zoomed in. You would need to calculate distortion for different focal lengths. Once you find the distortion coefficients for one lens, you can use those numbers for any shot made with that lens.

Comment: I doubt that the lens size is 26mm, maybe is 26 mm equivalent to a lens on a full frame. The sensor size on a phone is much smaller, so the lens length value must be way smaller.

Comment: @susu When you Google for iPhone 11 Pro focal length you find that value.

Comment: The **very first result** of a search for "Iphone 11 sensor size" results in this:. *[The 4.25mm wide angle lens (26mm FF equivalent) and the sensor size is 1/2.55″](https://photographylife.com/reviews/iphone-11-pro-camera#:~:text=iPhone%2011%20Pro%20%2F%20Pro%20Max%20Specifications&text=The%204.25mm%20wide%20angle,size%20is%201%2F2.55%E2%80%B3.)*