# how to change the render image size without changing camera settings

Tags: rendering

I was trying to change the size of the rendering area, the original size of the image is (1300x800)px, I want change to (2000x800)px (the red box area), but the rendering area does not become wider.
Is there any way to change the size without changing the camera settings?
[image: the size I wanted to render]

[image: the actual result when I changed the size]

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve your goal by changing the Sensor Fit setting under the camera settings from "Auto" to "Vertical".

[image]