# Determination the K-parameters for the distortion automatically

Tags: camera, tracking, distort

Something similar was ask [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622) but I would like to know if it is possible to know with Blender automatically the distortion parameters?

I have this picture [image: this picture] and I would like to know if Blender can give the amount of distortion automatically.

Comment: I'm not quite experienced in this topic, but how should anyone calculate a distortion when the only object in this image seems to be in an area where no distortion is visible? At least the outside edges seem more or less straight if I'm drawing a line along them. And the noise background isn't very good for measuring distortion either.

Comment: I am working with the image, it is for that I put it.
My question is how I can find the distortion parameters with this type of picture automatically with Blender

Comment: Well, I'd say: you can't, because there is no distortion visible. Lens distortion like bulging is not perspective distortion caused by vanishing point projection.

Comment: Ok I got it.
So how can I produce an image with Blender similar to that one then?

Comment: I would like to add some distortion to get a picture as close to reality as possible.

Comment: Rendered images in blender *usually* look like that. This seems equivalent to asking “how can I modify a chocolate chip cookies recipe to make chocolate chip cookies?” What is special about the image that you are not achieving at current?

Comment: I'm with @TheLabCat on this... This looks like a rectangular shaped object on the ceiling, with a picture taken from an angle below. Or actually it looks like some rectangular shaped object placed on the floor, and the picture is flipped. So you have to be more precise what you are struggling with... Creating a rectangular object? Pointing the camera at it in an angle?

Comment: I am working on a project where I want to recreate with Blender this image. My question is how can we validate the quality of the image created by Blender according to the real image?

Comment: I was struggling with the distortion. I would like to have the same amount of distortion between my real picture and the picture created with Blender