# Camera Tracking, What focal length to choose for a cell-phone cam if unknown?

Tags: camera, tracking

I am watching a tutorial on Cam Tracking, but I already met an obstacle in the beginning. 
I shot a footage, which I want to use for cam tracking, with a Cubot S350, 
a cheap cell phone from mainland China.

After having distributed the markers on the footage and calculated their tracks, I have to input at least two information about the cam:

- width of the CCD sensor
- focal length

I have searched for a long time, but I found only the sensor width and a couple of other parameters but none of them the focal length. Even on the internet page of the manufacturer inside the specs, there is just a blank space next to focal length.

Is there a way to find it out, do cellphones have a few typical focal lengths I could try, can I calculate the focal length from other given features?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lens specs of smartphones for camera tracking in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/lens-specs-of-smartphones-for-camera-tracking-in-blender)