# Sliding 3D objects with iPhone+Olloclip camera tracking

Tags: camera, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I am trying to create a movie clip where I'm walking, in a pretty straight line, through the furniture store where I work and have labels show up next to the different pieces of furniture. It is all working out fine except that the labels will not stay like glued in place beside the furniture except for in one specific part of the clip.

My guess is that I need to enter the exact focal length of the iPhone 5S+Olloclip wide angle lens I'm using, but the folks at Olloclip haven't been able to produce the data (yet).
Do you think I'm looking in the right direction, or is there a more likely cause for this sliding behaviour of the 3D labels vis-a-vis the background movie clip?

Comment: what is you solve error? do you have many trackers with a high error? Could you add a screen shot of blender in the Motion Tracking view, so we can get an idea of the scene.

Comment: Start by reading this: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)

Comment: And then  this: [Lens specs of smartphones for camera tracking in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/lens-specs-of-smartphones-for-camera-tracking-in-blender/16136#16136)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I decided to put up the clip in question on YouTube: https://youtu.be/CTGiWcM3ZqA

I had a solve error of 0.38 at the time the clip was saved, and the absolute highest tracker solve error was 0.87.

Comment: A big problem with troubleshooting for me now is that the scene goes completely out of whack as soon as I hit "Solve camera motion" again, and I have had to move the objects a lot afterwards, regardless of whether I refine for focal length, distortion et c. 
As you can see, the "Bloomingville" sign is sitting pretty solid. It is in around frame 99, and I might have used keyframes 1 and 99 last time I saved, at least that's what the user interface is showing when I open the file. Not using a zoom lens by the way and I'm using a small electronic gimbal to keep the shot steady.

Comment: Could you put the raw footage so that I can give it a try. Apparently, I see no reason why it shouldn't work fine but it's hard to see what's the problem without doing the tracking by myself.

Comment: @user49981: I'd appreciate it! I have a .mov file. Not sure how I can share it with you.