# Camera tracking problem - focal length seems wrong

Tags: tracking

I've tracked some footage with a view to replacing the background from the bottom of the fence panels up (this is a test shot for now). I shot the footage on a phone (13mm focal length) which Blender has extrapolated as 17.16mm. The solved camera seems off, though. I've made a line of dots going along the Y axis to test the perspective - I don't have an accurate floorplane, so have had to rotate these manually to match the camera - but you can see that even with Blender thinking the lens is longer than it is, it still doesn't look long enough:

[image]
[image]
[image]

To my eyes, there's too much parallax here. The track looked fine to me (average solve error 0.27px, and the dot that's selected in the screenshots doesn't slide around at all) but I'm obviously doing something wrong... any ideas?

Comment: Under Movie Clip Editor properties (N) > Track tab > Camera ... you can specify your camera specification directly. For more probably share your test footage and your simplified blend file.

Comment: probably related too https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16225/2214